# How to simplify and add sort in google spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using this code to move completed to one sheet but everything else from completed back to current. Is there a way to make it quicker like everything that isn't completed move back? Also is there a way to add sort by column 4 in the same code for the current sheet?

```
function onEdit() {
  // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
  // adjust the following variables to fit your needs
  // see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Current";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 4;
  var valueToWatch = "Completed";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Completed";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange); 
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Completed";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 4;
  var valueToWatch = "At Risk";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Current";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Completed";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 4;
  var valueToWatch = "Hold";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Current";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Completed";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 4;
  var valueToWatch = "Placed";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Current";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Completed";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 4;
  var valueToWatch = "Safe";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Current";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }

  var sheetNameToWatch = "Completed";

  var columnNumberToWatch = 4;
  var valueToWatch = "Other";
  var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Current";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

  if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
    sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, there is. To start, you need to address the code duplication you already have.  You'll also probably want to review the `Range#sort` method in Apps Script, and how to work with JavaScript arrays. An internet search should get you on your way. As-is, your request is too broad - you'll need to attempt to implement your desired feature, and ask for help in solving the issues that you are not able to solve.

Comment: @LorelaiBirch Hi. I'm looking at older questions that don't seem to have been resolved. How did you get on? Did you resolve your problem, or are you still looking for help?